# How to loop a .txt file line by line and wait for key board press to continue to read next line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Following is the current shell command I wrote. When running it prints the first line. Then it `read` the first letter of the next line and continue avoiding the pause that I expect until a keyboard key press. How to avoid that?

```
while read p; do
    echo "SEARCHING : $p ..."
    read -p "Press any key to continue... " -n1 -s
    echo -n "0047 SER 127.0.1.1 57000 \"$p\" 3" | nc -u 127.0.1.1 57000
done <Queries
```

**Queries file content**

```
Twilight
Jack
American Idol
Happy Feet
Twilight saga
Happy Feet
Happy Feet
Feet
....
....
```

**output of the shell script**

```
SEARCHING : Twilight ...
SEARCHING : ack ...
SEARCHING : merican Idol ...
SEARCHING : appy Feet ...
SEARCHING : wilight saga ...
....
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the body of the while loop inherits the stdin from the while, making the inner `read` read a line from the Queries-file, a quick fix is to specify input from the tty:

```
while IFS= read -r p; do
    echo "SEARCHING : $p ..."
    read -p "Press any key to continue... " -n1 -s < /dev/tty
    echo -n "0047 SER 127.0.1.1 57000 \"$p\" 3" | nc -u 127.0.1.1 57000
done <Queries
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!! I never heard of `/dev/tty`.

Comment: When the network command (`nc -u 127.0.1.1 57000`) is passed to a running listener. Entering does not move to the next line. Can you help me with that? @andlrc

Comment: I could get it done by putting `&` at the end of netcat  command